# Sending Data Iphone to PHP NSUTF8StringEncoding

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, nsurlconnection

I was following a video tutorail online to send data to a php file then store that in a database.

I'm really confused how it evan works as theres not post? Its just collecting information from variables. I few youtube comments say the same thing, but some how his works?

My code so far...

```
- (IBAction)Submit:(id)sender {

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bigwavemedia.co.uk/ios/contact.php?name=%@", nameField.text];

    //to execute php code
    NSData *dataURL = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:strURL]];

    NSString *strRes = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:dataURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSLog(@"%@", strRes);  
}
```

When I hit the submit button, evan though its linked up I get no response?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LwCyaGoRNWM

Comment: check data gat to php by get method or post method ??

Comment: the php is fine, i just need to work out what to add to the end of this code to send the string across once  Submit has been pressed.

Comment: yes i got it ..but in php accept data by get or post method ??

Comment: In php i am using Get to get the value from the url name =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Your case you Need to create [`NSURLConnection`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) for communication to server.

```
NSString *strURL=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.bigwavemedia.co.uk/ios/contact.php?name=%@", nameField.text];

NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:strURL];
self.request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

self.nsCon=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

            if(self.nsCon)
                self.receivedData=[[NSMutableData alloc] init];
            else
            {
                UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error",@"") message:NSLocalizedString(@"Not Connected Other View !!",@"") delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"OK",@"") otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }
```

And Write require delegate method of `NSURLConnection`, that describe in above link.

Comment: Where do I add this delegate? I opened the .h file and added @interface ContactViewControler : UIViewController <NSURLConnectionDelegate> is this correct?

Comment: yes...it is correct..or many exmple on google search it :) thanks :)

Comment: Sorry im confused on the last bit? Thanks

Comment: Could you please take a look at image link, its showing red on code i used, cant understand why.

Comment: it is object that decalre in .h file and use with self.obj_Name in .m file ...it is very simple bro :)

Comment: I will mark it correct just need to fix the .h then i guess, heres is a image of what i got. http://s13.postimage.org/9gdeziy6f/Screen_Shot_2013_03_06_at_15_02_20.png Sorry this is my first week on xcode and im trying to learn as much as i can.

Comment: @iPatel : can you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061813/arabic-text-getting-stored-as)