# Arabic text inserted by Autohotkey gets scrambled in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, autohotkey, arabic

[In the php section a similar problem was discussed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17061813/arabic-text-getting-stored-as). My problem has to do with either NotePad++ or either the AutoHotKey compiler. The Arabic text inside Notepad++ can by typed, saved and loaded correctly. When I compile with AutoHotKey and display the string containing the Arabic I typed with listvars, it shows a jumble of characters. Not just question marks like in the problem formulated at the php section, rather stuff like:
ط§ظ„ظ…ط¤ظ„ظپ
ںéè¢ں

Sometimes, some of the character are preserved, but slightly altered, sometimes it completely messes up.

In NotePad++ I experimented with some Arabic encoding settings under character settings. There are three settings in total, all of which scramble up my Arabic writing in NotePad++
These are:

1. ISO 8859-6
2. OEM 720
3. WINDOWS 1256

Lastly, I can read Arabic correctly from the clipboard, save it to a txt file, read from it again and display it correctly.

Comment: The issue is still standing as it is. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For non-ASCII text within the script file to be interpreted correctly by AutoHotkey, one of the following must be true:

1. The file is saved as UTF-8 with BOM.  In Notepad++, the option is **Encode in UTF-8**.
2. The file is saved as UTF-16 with BOM.  In Notepad++, the **Encode in UCS-2 Little Endian** option works so long as the file does not contain supplementary characters (U+10000 to U+10FFFF).
3. The file is saved with the system default ANSI codepage.  This implies that the characters it contains are all within that codepage.  In Notepad++, the option is **Encode in ANSI**.  In Windows 7, the codepage is set by the *Language for non-Unicode programs* option in the *Region and Language* control panel.
4. The file does not contain a BOM, but the `/CPn` command-line switch is used when running AutoHotkey.exe, where n is the identifier of the codepage used to save the file.  See [Code Page Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756) at MSDN for a list.

UTF-8 is recommended.

Refer to [Script File Codepage](http://l.autohotkey.net/docs/Scripts.htm#cp) in the AutoHotkey documentation.